# dotnet build does not see referenced project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

### Steps to reproduce

Create `net461` Core webproject referencing ClassLibrary of same 4.6.1 in VS2017.
In lib define

```
public class X
{
    [Required] // using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    public bool Q { get; set; }
}
```

In webapp use it: `new ClassLibrary1.X();`

Builds in VS, builds via msbuild in cmd, OK.

Run `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` and you will get

```
Class1.cs(5,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\coretest\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Cannot find project info for 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\coretest\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj'. This can indicate a missing project reference. [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\coretest\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj]
```

`dotnet --info` output:
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  e53429feb4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0

Comment: Could you try with `.Net Standard` project?

Comment: Yes, it is compiled with `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>` library.

Comment: (after commenting `[Required]` of course)

Comment: Maybe I forget something and with VS2017-version cli we still must build net461 with `--no-dep` option, then its "fine".